# Drawing text to right side of tab prevents new tabs from having text

Tags: python, pyside6

I am trying to draw my tab text to the right side of the tab in part so it does not cut off for long tab names and it looks nicer (at least to me). However, my `paintEvent` seems to prevent the default behavior of setting the tab text. Where am I going wrong?

```
from PySide6 import QtWidgets
from PySide6 import QtCore
from PySide6.QtCore import Signal, QSize
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QLabel, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QStyle, QStyleOptionTab, QStylePainter


class ShrinkTabBar(QtWidgets.QTabBar):
    _widthHint = -1
    _initialized = False
    _recursiveCheck = False

    addClicked = Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ShrinkTabBar, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setElideMode(QtCore.Qt.TextElideMode.ElideLeft)
        self.setExpanding(False)
        self.setMovable(True)
        self.addButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.parent(), text='+')
        self.addButton.clicked.connect(self.addClicked)
        self._recursiveTimer = QtCore.QTimer(singleShot=True, timeout=self._unsetRecursiveCheck, interval=0)
        self._tabHint = QSize(0, 0)
        self._minimumHint = QSize(0, 0)

    def _unsetRecursiveCheck(self):
        self._recursiveCheck = False


    def _computeHints(self):
        if not self.count() or self._recursiveCheck:
            return
        self._recursiveCheck = True

        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionTab()
        self.initStyleOption(opt, 0)
        width = self.style().pixelMetric(QtWidgets.QStyle.PixelMetric.PM_TabBarTabHSpace, opt, self)
        iconWidth = self.iconSize().width() + 2
        self._minimumWidth = width + iconWidth

        # default text widths are arbitrary
        fm = self.fontMetrics()
        self._minimumCloseWidth = self._minimumWidth + fm.horizontalAdvance('x' * 4) + iconWidth
        self._defaultWidth = width + fm.horizontalAdvance('x' * 26)
        self._defaultHeight = super().tabSizeHint(0).height()
        self._minimumHint = QtCore.QSize(self._minimumWidth, self._defaultHeight)
        self._defaultHint = self._tabHint = QtCore.QSize(self._defaultWidth, self._defaultHeight)

        self._initialized = True
        self._recursiveTimer.start()

    def _updateSize(self):
        if not self.count():
            return
        frameWidth = self.style().pixelMetric(
            QtWidgets.QStyle.PixelMetric.PM_DefaultFrameWidth, None, self.parent())
        buttonWidth = self.addButton.sizeHint().width()
        self._widthHint = (self.parent().width() - frameWidth - buttonWidth) // self.count()
        self._tabHint = QtCore.QSize(min(self._widthHint, self._defaultWidth), self._defaultHeight)
        # dirty trick to ensure that the layout is updated
        if not self._recursiveCheck:
            self._recursiveCheck = True
            self.setIconSize(self.iconSize())
            self._recursiveTimer.start()


    # BUG: is somewhere in here
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QStylePainter(self)
        option = QStyleOptionTab()

        for index in range(self.count()):
            self.initStyleOption(option, index)
            tabRect = self.tabRect(index)
            tabRect.moveLeft(10)
            painter.drawControl(QStyle.ControlElement.CE_TabBarTabShape, option)
            painter.drawText(tabRect,
                             QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignVCenter |
                             QtCore.Qt.TextFlag.TextDontClip,
                             self.tabText(index))


class ShrinkTabWidget(QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    addClicked = Signal()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._tabBar = ShrinkTabBar(self)
        self.setTabBar(self._tabBar)
        self._tabBar.setTabsClosable(True)

        self._tabBar.addClicked.connect(self.get_page_choices)


    def get_page_choices(self):
        selection_page = QLabel("This worked")
        index = self.addTab(selection_page, 'New Tab')   # BUG: New Tab does not show up only a blank
        self._tabBar.setCurrentIndex(index)   # Set as current tab
```

Comment: Why are you moving the left of `tabRect`? Do you realize that, other than using an arbitrary value, you are practically placing **all** tab rectangles with their left (the `x` coordinate) at the same position?

Comment: Are you sure that is not a "relative" drawing?

Comment: Looking here: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtCore/QRect.html#PySide6.QtCore.PySide6.QtCore.QRect

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. In order to be "relative", a QPainter `translate()` function should have been called. While this sometimes happens within the QStyle function such as `drawControl()`, they also do such things within a context (with a `save()` and `restore()`) so that the painter is always restored to the original state. `moveLeft()` moves the rectangle to an absolute horizontal position that completely ignores its previous coordinates, unless done with *relative* computation. If you want to *shift* the rectangle, you should do `tabRect.moveLeft(tabRect.x() + 10)` or `tabRect.translate(10, 0)`.

Comment: `Moves the rectangle horizontally, leaving the rectangle’s left edge at the given x coordinate. The rectangle’s size is unchanged.` Too me, that implies it is moving from each tab's left side, no? This documentation is not clear to me, at the very least.

Comment: Yes, but your given `x coordinate` is **absolute**. The function is named `moveLeft`, not `shiftLeft`: if you have a rectangle that starts at 100 and you call `moveLeft(10)`, then the rectangle will have its left **at** 10, not 110. Also, widget coordinates are *always* relative to the widget origin point: the top left corner, which in relative coordinates is always `(0, 0)`, just like any relative Cartesian coordinate system. Just try to print the original `tabRect` origin point and you will see that each tab rect is relative to the widget origin.

Comment: the `moveLeft` versus `shiftLeft` makes a lot of sense! Thanks!

Comment: If I may, considering some of your previous questions and statements, I suggest you to do a review of basic aspects of geometry, specifically about Cartesian system, Euclidean space, relative coordinates and nomenclature. Also, Qt is known for having a strict naming convention; don't underestimate that aspect (even if it has the drawback that sometimes they have extremely *long* names); a function is a thing that *does* something, so its name should precisely *describe* that action: "move" means to put something in a specific point, not a point related to its previous position.

Comment: If I may (again), it seems clear that you're still learning Qt basics while trying to adapt some code without completely understanding it (which is completely fine). The code you're using from my post is based on complex aspects related to QPainter (the common way of "drawing" in Qt), QStyle (the interface used to draw widgets and compute geometries in Qt) and standard QWidget aspects. I strongly suggest you to take your time to do some thorough research on those subjects: while trial and error can be effective in some cases, it can also be very a frustrating learning method.